# "sudo update-grub" = "failed to get canonical path of /cow" Why?

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, radeon, amd-graphics

On Xubuntu 20.04 LTS live USB, I'm trying to add `radeon.modeset=0` to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` in the file `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` so that it reads:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0"
```

and make that change permanent.

This is to prevent one of my discrete graphic cards (Radeon) from starting on boot.

BUT...

When I `sudo update-grub`  after making the above change, it says `failed to get canonical path of /cow`...

1. How can I fix that?
2. Is it necessary to `sudo update-grub`  after making the change in order for the change to stick?
3. The change saves successfully and doesn't give a read-only error. However, when I restart, the change is no longer there.
4. I don't want to make the USB persistent.
5. The USB was created with UNetbootin.
6. My main concern is the disabling of the discrete graphic card rather than the title of this question. So if the fix to the title is too involved and the disabling of the graphic card could be accomplished with less work, I'm all for it.
7. https://imgur.com/FCrUBHh
8. Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: COW means copy-on-write.  The *live* system is intentionally RO, if you want to make changes, you re-create the ISO & re-write it, or via persistence. The `update-grub` is designed to work on an installed system, not RO/COW system (changes made are made in the COPY which is in RAM, and are thus lost on reboot or subsequent boots; ie. the copy-on-write doesn't change the RO image)

Comment: Aha. ".. or via persistence." OK, so if I make the USB persistent, then make the change, how can I undo the persistence and return it to non-persistent again, but keep the change I've made? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I read that 5 times but I still couldn't understand haha. Sorry. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: You can not update-grub on a Live USB or a Persistent USB by runnin the command. However you can edit both `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `/syslinux` on a live USB made using UNetbootin. It can be done directly on a Windows computer and as administrator on a Linux computer. It has been explained on the three other questions you have opened on the same subject. If there is something you still do not understand with those answers please leave another comment there.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron like I said, it didn't work. https://m.imgur.com/aaB7Rgm

Comment: @JJrussel: That link looks good as long as you are booting the USB in UEFI mode. I was under the impression that you are booting the USB in BIOS mode. When booting a UNetbootin made Ubuntu 20.04 USB in BIOS mode you need to edit `/syslinux.cfg`, not `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` Unetbootin boots in BIOS mode using the Syslinux bootloader not the GRUB2 bootloader.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron How do I make sure that it's working after I make the changes?

Comment: @JJrussel: I am not sure how you test if `radeon.modeset=0` is working, I have a Nvidia card. When I was testing the method I used `nomodeset` instead. I could tell that was working because the resolution was not as fine. To make sure that syslinux.cfg has been changed, press shift when booting, at the language screen press `Esc` then `F6` you should see the command line and it should include `radeon.modeset=0`. I think `cat /proc/cmdline` should also work.

Comment: What about in UNetbootin?

Comment: With UNetbootin press `Tab` after the menu comes up, and you should see the command line, it should contain `radeon.modeset=0`.

Comment: See this excellent [comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/1316042/884636), which explains it pretty well: Either edit `/isolinux/txt.cfg` or `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` on the live usb, depending on whether you boot in UEFI or Legacy. Tested.